# Como hacer que en el constructor no tenga que poner los parametros de su superclase completo

Tags: java

Tengo una clase principal llamado equipo a la cual he creado una clase llamado luchadores donde he puesto variables internas repetidas y le he extendido al equipo y por ultimo cada raza.

en la raza sayajin cuando hago el constructor me pasa esto:

```
public class Saiyajin extends Luchadores {
private int ptosAtaqueKi;
int [] estados;

public Saiyajin(String n, String u, int vi, int res, int atFi,int atKi) {
    super(n, u, vi, res, atFi);

    this.ptosAtaqueKi=atKi;
    if (u.equals("Universo 6")) {
        this.estados=new int [3];
    }
    if (u.equals("Universo 7")) {

    }
    this.estados= new int [5];


}
```

No consigo que no me salga por parametros del constructor los dos primeros String que son del equipo adjunto las demas clases padres:

```
 public class Equipos {
private String nombreDios;
private String universo;


 public Equipos(String n,String u){
    this.nombreDios=n;
    this.universo=u;
}
```

Esta es la clase que me afecta y los dos pimeros String de la raza son de esta clase

```
public  class Luchadores extends Equipos {
private int ptosVida;
private int ptosResistencia;
private int ptsAtaqueFisico;

public Luchadores(String n, String u,int vi,int res,int atFi) {
    super(n, u);
    this.ptosVida=vi;
    this.ptosResistencia=res;
    this.ptsAtaqueFisico=atFi;
}
```

Comment: no termino de entender tu problema...

Comment: Explica brevemente cómo se relacionan las clases entre ellas y tendrás la respuesta de tu problema. Por ejemplo: ¿por qué `Luchadores` extiende de `Equipos`? Ya la forma de nombrar las clases (en plural) hace que te pierdas rápido en los conceptos.

Comment: Declara `nombreDios`y `universo` como `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

Al extender de la clase Luchadores, la clase Saiyajin debe contener todos los atributos de dicha clase ya que los hereda. Echa un ojo a este enlace sobre la [herencia](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Si no quieres que tu clase Saiyajin contenga dichos atributos podrías generar distintas clases Luchadores que contengan los atributos que necesites. Y extender de estas la clase Saiyajin.

Aunque como te indican en comentarios, la pregunta sería ¿cual es la necesidad de que Luchadores extienda de Equipos?

Comment: un equipo tiene 3 luchadores